# retrieve a specific section of a webpage

Tags: bash, list, dynamically-generated

I need to populate a list in a BASH script with data retrieved from a portion of a webpage. Currently, I have manually created a static list but I want the list contents to be generated dynamically. That way if new items get added to the page, subsequent runs of the script will reflect those new items.

source page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060

I would like to extract the section entitled "macOS, iOS, and tvOS" to wind up with a list like:

```
updateServers="appldnld.apple.com 80  
gg.apple.com 80   
gg.apple.com 443  
gnf-mdn.apple.com 443  
gnf-mr.apple.com 443  
gs.apple.com 80  
gs.apple.com 443  
ig.apple.com 443  
mesu.apple.com 80  
mesu.apple.com 443  
ns.itunes.apple.com 443  
oscdn.apple.com 80  
oscdn.apple.com 443  
osrecovery.apple.com 80  
osrecovery.apple.com 443  
skl.apple.com 443  
swcdn.apple.com 80  
swdist.apple.com 443  
swdownload.apple.com 80  
swdownload.apple.com 443  
swpost.apple.com 80  
swscan.apple.com 443  
updates-http.cdn-apple.com 80  
updates.cdn-apple.com 443  
xp.apple.com 443"
```

Ultimately I'd like to output each section of the page into its own separate list, but for now the portion above is my main concern.

Thank you all in advance. This is a great community.

Answer (score 0):

A HTML parser is a better tool for this type tasks (e.g. Ruby's Nokogiri or Python's Beautifulsoup). For a pure-Bash solution you can use this script (assuming `-P` support for grep):

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060 -O- \
    | \grep -ziP "(?s)<h3>macos.*?<h3>" \
    | xargs -0 \
    | \grep -P "<tr><td>|<td>[\d, ]+</td>" \
    | sed 's:.*<td>\(.*\)</td>:\1:'
```

How it works:

1. wget with `-O-` downloads the website and sends it to standard output
2. `grep -ziP "(?s)..."` uses PCRE to make a multi-line search from one  until the next one
3. the rest of the script gets the text inside host and port columns

Output:

```
$ script.sh
appldnld.apple.com
80
gg.apple.com
443, 80
...
80
updates.cdn-apple.com
443
xp.apple.com
443
```

Comment: my output doesn't match yours, i am using macOS. I receive the following   `grep: invalid option -- z
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: It seems that your grep version does not support `-z` option. You can check grep version with `grep --version`. This solution is for GNU grep